# What kind of slide rails do I need?

Tags: hardware, rack, rackmount

I need to install two servers from Supermicro in a 19" rack with round holes on the vertical rails. The Repon slides that came with the servers typically install in a 19" rack with square holes. Most of the other rails we use in the company are from General Devices (C-300 series), but those will not fit on the side of the Supermicros because of the tab-type mounting system used by the Repon slides.

[image]

Some documentation I found on the Repon website mentioned a "transfer bracket", but they don't sell that product (that I could find) and I can't locate a bracket that seems correct.

So my question is, with a rail depth of 26.5" in a 19" rack with round holes on the vertical, what kind of rail slides can I get (and where)? Hopefully a simple question with a simple answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supermicro offers a *Threaded Rail Adapter Set for Round Hole Racks (MCP-290-00060-0N)* which sounds like what you're looking for exactly.

Comment: That's great, thanks! It's out of stock, but it's a good lead.